# Java documentation says that hs_err_pid will be written to /tmp if current dir is not writable, but it is not

Tags: java

I work on a bunch of Java services that run in containers in k8s.  I think we're not properly configured to integrate any "hs_err_pid" files that get written, so I'm experimenting with this.

We're still running Java 8.  I'm reading through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BGBCIEFC , and I find the following statement:

> If the file cannot be created in the specified directory (due to insufficient space, permission problem, or another issue), then the file is created in the temporary directory for the operating system. The temporary directory is /tmp.

So, I went into a container running a Java process.  I looked at /tmp, and I saw that it was writable.  I looked at the command line of the Java process, verifying that it doesn't set the ErrorFile location.  I checked the "ps" output to get the pid.  I executed "kill -11 ".  I then checked the "ps" output again, and I saw that a new Java process was running.  I then checked "/tmp" for a "hs_err_pid" file.  It was not there.

Is there something I'm missing here, or is this documentation not correct?

Comment: Is there a point from that? Were you thinking I didn't check in the current working directory?  It's not there either, and it wouldn't be, because we specifically make the filesystem read-only.  I also checked the perms on /tmp, and it is clearly "drwxrwxrwt", so it is writable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [systemd PrivateTmp](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ServicesPrivateTmp) strikes again!

> http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/security.html
>
> **Service-Private /tmp** Another very simple but powerful configuration switch is PrivateTmp=:
>
> ```
> ...
> [Service]
> ExecStart=...
> PrivateTmp=yes
> ... If enabled this option will ensure that the /tmp directory the service will see is private and isolated from the host system's /tmp.
> ```
>
> /tmp traditionally has been a shared space for all local services and
> users.
>
> Over the years it has been a major source of security problems for a
> multitude of services. Symlink attacks and DoS vulnerabilities due to
> guessable /tmp temporary files are common.
>
> By isolating the service's /tmp from the rest of the host, such
> vulnerabilities become moot.

SUGGESTION: Try searching for "hs_err_pid" elsewhere.  For example:

```
find / name "hs_err_pid*" -print 2> /dev/null
```

You might find it in a subdirectory like this:

```
/tmp/systemd-private-nABCDE/tmp/hs_err_pid
```

If you wish, you can disable it on a per-service basis in your systemd configuration.

Comment: Well, first, the file is not found in any subdirectory of /tmp. I didn't really have to do that search, I can see that there are no subdirs in /tmp.  Second, if it wasn't clear, I don't care about the hosts "/tmp" directory. I am only looking inside the container. I doubt this is an issue with Linux, I think it's entirely a Java issue.

Comment: I disagree: the problem is almost certainly *NOT* "Java".  It could be the OS, your Kubernetes/Docker container, Spring (I'm guessing maybe this is a Spring Boot app?) or "something else".  As a "first, easy" troubleshooting step, I would definitely consider running "find"; at either/both the OS and/or container levels.

Comment: Ok, well, doing this isn't easy.  I'm unable to get to the node the container runs in, and running a plain "find" in the entire container fileysystem eventually fails with a 137 error code (out of memory).  I also tried doing 'ls "*/hs_err_pid*"', and 'ls */*/hs_err_pid*'', and so on, until that also failed with a 137, none of which found the file (SO seems to mangle those command lines).

Comment: OK - thank you. I'm glad you tried.  The points I was trying to make: 1) the files could be elsewhere besides absolute path "/tmp" (despite the documentation implying otherwise), 2) the files could be named something besides "hs_err_pid" (for example, they might have a suffix), 3) the "root cause" could be in many places: OS, Container, framework (e.g Tomcat or Spring Boot:, assuming this isn't just a simple cmd-line Java app), etc. etc.  But I don't have the wherewithal to try reproducing the problem on Docker right now. So I'm out of suggestions.  Sorry :(

Comment: PS: If you haven't already tried it, explicitly set JVM option: [-XX:ErrorFile=/path/to/logfile](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/vmoptions-jsp.html)

Comment: If it matters, I think I've determined that it very likely is writing the file to /tmp, but as I'm killing the process that is the entrypoint to the container, the instant after it writes that file, the container is exiting and then restarting, blowing away the container filesystem. I will definitely have to mount a persistent volume for this.